# Magento2: How to get images inserted in custom theme's media folder?

Tags: magento2, theme, media-images

I'm trying to get image which is inserted in `/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/media` folder using following code but it's shows 404 not found. I have also apply cache clean & static content deploy command but still not working. I'm using below code in my phtml file:-

```
$mediaurl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$image = $mediaurl."myimg.png";
echo $image;
```

So is it possible to get images of media folder in M2? Any suggestion should be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('media/myimg.png');
```

Comment: Hi. Still not working.

Comment: @Raj i am using same code for display image. do as follow: copy your image in vendor/theme/web/media/ and add this code in phtml file to get this image to display